# failed to open stream and permission denied - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to copy an image from https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkoAp.jpg to localhost.  It gives me a

> Warning: `copy(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkoAp.jpg)` [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in `/var/www/html/test/timg`

The folder `timg` has got 777 access

```
copy("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkoAp.jpg","timg/avcsLXI.jpg");
```

`move_uploaded_file()` throws the same error

I have seen various examples but not seen one with copy.  I do not want to use fopen or curl for this purpose.

Comment: The file you're writing to has to have 777 as well, assuming that `timg` exists already. Note that copy will be using the same background mechanisms as fopen would be anyways, it just condenses a few lines of php code into the single copy() call. You're not avoiding fopen - you're just hiding the fact that it's being used.

Comment: timg already exists, the "http://i.imgur.com/avcsLXI.jpg" is a live img url.  Why does that have to be 777?

Comment: what are your permissions on the test folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the desitination *filename*, not just the directory.

This works for me:

```
copy("http://i.imgur.com/avcsLXI.jpg","timg/avcsLXI.jpg");
```

Note that some webhosts don't allow URLs as the source path for security reasons, this will only work if "fopen wrappers" have been enabled.

Comment: Sorry yes that is how it was done in my code already.  Editing the question.

Comment: I got the allow_url_fopen = On for php.ini, Is there anything I need to look for?

Comment: Then it seems to come down to the folder permission. The above code works for me, I tried it on multiple machines of mine. Double check the owner of your folder, the user that Apache is running as, and the folder permissions. It has to be there somewhere.

Comment: Does the folder owner have to be apache, as its the logged user

Comment: It shouldn't have to be, but I'd troubleshoot that regardless. Change the owner, reset permissions again. Your error is "Permission denied in...timg" so that's the issue.

Comment: chgrp and chown -R apache timg

Comment: Checked on my online servers and it works fine, wonder why it does not work on my laptop even though the fopen is set to ON in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

If `timg` is a folder, then there's your problem. `copy()` works on FILES for both the source AND destination. YOu can't have just a folder for the destination,b ecause copy will try to replace the folder with the file you're copying from. So

```
copy("http://i.imgur.com/avcsLXI.jpg","timg"); // folder only, WRONG
copy("http://i.imgur.com/avcsLXI.jpg","timg/thepic.jpg"); // correct, folder+file
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question to provide path as timg/avcsLXI.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for an alternative other than fopen or curl, you could use wget:

```
shell_exec('wget -P timg/avcsLXI.jpg http://i.imgur.com/avcsLXI.jpg');
```

Comment: if your using GET/POST variables for wget URLs .. run them through htmlentities($str,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') first .