# Warning: copy(files): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, html

I am trying to download some file from http site to my folder in localhost, but I am getting this error `Warning: copy(files): failed to open stream: Permission denied`. I have tried setting the permission of the folder `files` and unchecked Readonly, but doesn't stay unchecked the square fills somehow with a blue color. Also tried installing different software for enabling it also tried going to Properties->Security and enabling from there, but still nothing. This is the script:

PHP

```
<?php
function recurse_copy($source,$dst) { 
  if(is_dir($source)) {
    $dir_handle=opendir($source);
    while($file=readdir($dir_handle)){
        if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
            if(is_dir($source."/".$file)){
                if(!is_dir($dest."/".$file)){
                    mkdir($dest."/".$file);
                }
                copy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);
            } else {
                copy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir_handle);
  } else {
    copy($source, $dst);
  }
}
$source = isset($_POST['source']) ? $_POST['source'] : ''; // this would be a http://www.domain.com/folder
$dst = 'files'; //also tried: F:/SERVER/htdocs/scripts/download-files-with-specific-extention/files
recurse_copy($source,$dst);
?>
```

HTML

```
<form id="form" name="download" action="" method="post">
  Source <input class="field" type="text" name="source" value="<?php echo $source; ?>"><br>
  Destination <input class="field" type="text" name="destination" value="<?php echo $dst; ?>">
  <input id="button" type="submit" name="download" value="Get Files">
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [failed to open stream and permission denied - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280795/failed-to-open-stream-and-permission-denied-php)

Comment: @kingkero, it's different than that one because this script is doing recursive copying. So it should copy all files from folder without knowing the files.

Comment: Well it seems quite familiar, aren't you too trying to use `copy()` with a HTTP source and encounter `failed to open stream: Permission denied`?

Comment: I see where you are poiting, but the problem is that in the copy function, the error is pointing on the 'files' folder (localhost) which is on my computer not on the HTTP site.